# User input with $$ messes up Variable

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to get username and password from the user via parameters from the commandline.

My issue here is that if I use a passwort like `Test$$123` and it will see the `$$` ad the PID and messes up the userpassword. Now it is `Test4365123`.
Same goes for `$1`, `$2` etc..

Is there any way of getting rid of this "interpretation" an just get the "real" value?

Note: the issue is happening at `pass=$2`, so I can't just escape any character. (What I tryied ): )

Here is my code:

```
# Input
TEMP=`getopt -o ap: --long admin:,pass: -n 'add-vhost' -- "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --admin ) admin="$2"; shift 2 ;;
    -p | --pass ) pass="$2"; shift 2 ;;
    -- ) shift; break ;;
    * ) exit; break ;;
  esac
done

echo $admin
echo $pass
```

Comment: Please try changing \` \` to `TEMP=$(...)`? What is your `getopt --version` output?

Comment: @KamilCuk verion: 2.33.1 and with the change it's stil the same

Comment: Is the issue happening at `pass="$2"`, or at `echo $pass`?  Have you tried `echo "$pass"`?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` instead of just `set`?  That `eval` is certainly going to interpolate the string.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the issue is happening at ``pass="$2"``, the echo at the and is how I discovered why it didn't work.

Comment: How are you passing the password? `if I use a passwort like` How do you "use it like"? Could you please post the command line you use with your program? Are you running `./your_program "Test$$123"`? Or `./your_program Test$$123`?

Comment: @chepner I tried replacing pass="$2" with echo $2 and it echoed the exact same - wrong - input

Comment: Are you doing something like `./script --pass "Test$$123"`? Your script never sees the `$$`; it's expanded to the current process ID by the shell before `script` even runs.

Comment: @KamilCuk ``bash ./test.bash --admin user --pass Test$$123`` is the command line. I said passwords like, because the user password could change and it just could be $1 in the password.

Comment: o'gamingSCV : There is nothing wrong with your assignment to `pass`. The havoc happens in the `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

> bash ./test.bash --admin user --pass Test$$123 is the command line.

`$$` is expanded **before** your script is even run. You have to quote or escape special characters, like `$`, to prevent them from being expanded.

```
bash ./test.bash --admin user --pass 'Test$$123'
# or
bash ./test.bash --admin user --pass Test\$\$123
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this and all worked great, but I cant ask the user so look for any $-signs and escape them :( so it has to be handeled by the script

Comment: It cannot be handled by the script.  The script never sees it.  If the user doesn't know how to use a shell, they shouldn't be allowed to run your script.

Comment: `but I cant ask the user` From the perspective of your script, the user inputted `Test4365123`. If the user does not want `$$` to be expanded, the user may not use shell. The shell, that the user is running to input the line, is expanding `$$`.

Comment: From another perspective, passwords shouldn't be passed as command-line arguments, since those are visible to anyone on the machine. The script should probably be prompting for a password that can be read from the terminal (*not* standard input), or better yet, let the program that actually *needs* the password do the prompting.

Answer (score 0):

If the user cannot use the shell properly, you can change `--pass` to simply *prompt* the user to type their password. Read from standard input, the string will not be subject to shell expansion.

```
# Changes: -p and --pass do not take arguments; they are
# just used to change the value of get_pass from 0 to 1.
TEMP=`getopt -o ap: --long admin:,pass -n 'add-vhost' -- "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi
eval set -- "$TEMP"
get_pass=0
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --admin ) admin="$2"; shift 2 ;;
    -p | --pass ) get_pass=1 ;;
    -- ) shift; break ;;
    * ) exit; break ;;
  esac
done

# Read the password directly from the terminal (not standard
# input). If you do want to allow reading from standard input,
# remove the input redirection.
#
# Remove -s if you want the user to be able to see the password
# as they type.
if [[ "$get_pass" = 1 ]]; then
    read -ps 'Password: ' pass < /dev/tty
fi

echo $admin
echo $pass
```

Comment: ``getopt: unrecognized option '--admin'
Try 'getopt --help' for more information.
Terminating...`` this output

Comment: (@o'gamingSCV Just to  note, I completely overhauled this answer, if you  would like to delete your comment.)